# How to include asset fields in query in php?

Tags: craft3, query

I am trying to figure out how to return asset field(s) in a PHP entry query. Also if I could learn how to return "custom fields" when returning an Object that would be great too! Right now I am having to specify `asArray()` to even get access to most of my "custom fields"

As as example: I have a Vehicle Entry which has a custom field with the handle of price (number field) and another custom field (asset field) with the handle of images. When I execute the query without specifying the asArray() param I cannot find the custom fields included in the results. But if I specify asArray() then they are all there with the exception of my images field which I think is because it is an asset field or possible because it can be a collection of images? How can I make sure all the fields tied to an entry are returned in my query?

Here are some examples of queries and the corresponding results:

PHP Query **without asArray()**:

```
$entry_query = Entry::find()
->section('inventory')
->all();
```

Returns: 
[image]

PHP Query results **with asArray()**:

```
$entry_query = Entry::find()
->section('inventory')
->asArray();
```

[image]

However even when specifing to make the result set an array I still cannot figure out how to include the 'images' field.

The images is a field added to the section (see below)
[image]

I am having a difficult time finding an answer via the documentation or an example of someone doing the same. All the examples i find are for the template side in twig.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the `asArray()` part, as the object has all you need:

```
// This bit returns only the query that defines what objects to get
$entryQuery = Entry::find()->section('inventory');

/*
 * This will get you one object, based on the query. 
 * Use all() if you want an array of objects
 */
$entry = $entryQuery->one();

// Of course, this could be written as
$entry = Entry::find()->section('inventory')->one();

/* 
 * Thanks to Yii2's magic getters and setters, 
 * and the way Craft uses them, any custom field can be 
 * obtained by using the field's handle:
 */
$customFieldContent = $entry->customFieldHandle;

/*
 * If the custom field is any kind of relation field (assets, categories, tags ...),
 * this custom field attribute would return a new query object.
 * You'd need to call all() or one() again to get the actual related objects:
 */
 $images = $entry->customImagesFieldHandle->all();

/*
 * To improve performance, you can eager load the images:
 */
$entry = Entry::find()
    ->section('inventory')
    ->with(['customImagesFieldHandle'])
    ->one();

/*
 * ... which would result in an array of images as the value of the
 * customImagesFieldHandle attribute
 */
$images = $entry->customImagesFieldHandle;
```

Some light reading:

[About entry queries](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html)

[About eager loading](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/eager-loading-elements.html#eager-loading-image-transform-indexes)

Addition, after seeing exactly what it is you want. Use Craft's (or actually Yii's) [ArrayHelper map() function](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-array#building-maps) to loop through your entries and mapping entry content to what you want:

```
use craft\helpers\ArrayHelper

// Use the map() function to do what you want
$entries = Entry::find()->section('inventory')->all();

$entriesAsYouWantThem = ArrayHelper::map($entries, 'id', function($entry) {
    return (object)[
        'images' => $entry->images->all(), // or without all, if you use ->with()
        'price' => $entry->price,
        'year' => $entry->year,
        ... All other fields
    ];
});
```

Comment: How would I create one dataset with the field data and the images in it? Also if I query just the section as an object there is not field data included in that set either. I need one set of data with the asset field (images) and all the other fields.

Comment: I think I may need to build out a string out on the server side. I guess I could loop through the results from the first query and in that loop get the assets for it and build some string? Ideally I would avoid that.

Comment: Well you put me on the right track. using the with didn't yield any of the fields i needed. I ended up querying all entries, looped over them and got the content i needed, and modified that entry to included what i needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing.

```
    $vehicles = array(); // empty container to hold our modified entries
    // Lets Query our Inventory - all of it
    /** @var array $entry_query   the name of our query to get our inventory - return a list of inventory after we execute query */
    $entries = Entry::find()
        ->section('inventory')
        ->all();

    foreach($entries as $entry) {
        /*
         * Let's get all our custom fields we want
         * to include with our entries
         */
        // Get our image field and add to result set - because it's an asset field this returns a query object
        $ourimages = $entry->images->all(); // get all our images
        $price = $entry->price;
        $featured = $entry->featureThisVehicle;
        $make = $entry->make;
        $model = $entry->model;
        $year = $entry->year;
        $description = $entry->description;
        $inventoryStatus = $entry->inventoryStatus;
        $bodyStyle = $entry->bodyStyle;
        $color = $entry->color;
        $miles = $entry->miles;
        $vin = $entry->vin;
        $stkid = $entry->stkid;

        // cast out entry object as an array - so we can add props to it
        $entry = (array)$entry;

        // add our custom fields to our newly casted entry array
        $entry['images'] = $ourimages;
        $entry['price'] = $price;
        $entry['featured'] = $featured;
        $entry['make'] = $make;
        $entry['model'] = $model;
        $entry['year'] = $year;
        $entry['description'] = $description;
        $entry['inventoryStatus'] = $inventoryStatus;
        $entry['bodyStyle'] = $bodyStyle;
        $entry['color'] = $color;
        $entry['miles'] = $miles;
        $entry['vin'] = $vin;
        $entry['stkid'] = $stkid;

        // Recast back to object just cause (not really necessary since we are json_encode'ing this)
        $entry = (object)$entry;
        array_push($vehicles, $entry);
    }

    return json_encode($vehicles);
```

Comment: See my addition for a simpler, shorter way to do this ...